# Every time I try to update I get this.. And cant install software

Tags: updates

```
sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,811 B]
Err:2 http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
  Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:4 http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease         
  Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease 
  Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Ign:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease     
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.247 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Release file for http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 29min 28s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any ideas? Ubuntu Mate, 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 isn't an EOL (*end-of-life*) release until 2030-April (5 years of standard support + 5 years of ESM support) so why are you trying to use old-releases ? (where EOL releases get packages from).  You need to restore your sources to use http://archive.ubuntu.com/ again

Comment: The Grub Customizer PPA (https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) is no longer publicly available on releases post 2018.  That source is no longer useful & should be removed.

Comment: It appears you may have copied the sources.list from an install of an unsupported release and done a global replace to 'focal'. That is not a recipe for success.